# Google Maps not loading in site

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to integrate Google Maps into my site and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have the code exactly like Google does, except I changed a little bit of the CSS, but I swapped out mine for theirs and it still didn't work. Does someone see something that I don't?

```
<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    background: #CCC;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Comment: You aren't calling the `initMap` method.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qyn1bbzo/).  Either add a `&callback=initMap` to your script include or use an onload function to call it.

Comment: OOps.  geocodezip is exactly right.  Somewhere you need `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>` per the instructions on [this page.](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map#the_googlemapsmap_object)  You are missing the callback.

Comment: Gotcha. I followed the directions on the link you gave me and it works, I just can't figure out how to add a default address in it. I don't get why Google doesn't specify you need to create an API key.

Comment: Thanks guys! I figured out the location part too. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to actually run the initialization function. Just call the function after the function declaration, and it works.

```
function initMap() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
      zoom: 8
  });
}
initMap();
```

Edit: As mentioned in several comments to the question, this can also be achieved by adding `&callback=initMap` to the script src:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer>
```

Comment: Recommendation: when somebody posts an great answer, even though its a comment, just upvote the comment.  Kudos to geocodezip

Comment: @zipzit If there were any comments when I started writing this, that's exactly what I would've done. That wasn't the case though.

Comment: @zipzit: nobody will know that this problem has been solved when there isn't a "real" answer(which may be accepted)

Comment: none of the comments includes ***Just call the function after the function declaration*** ...this answer is a  different approach with the same result